# Python Crypto AES encryption/decryption work misunderstanding

Tags: encryption, aes

Please, explain me how it can be.

As you can see:

```
plain != decrypt(encrypt(plain))
```

[image]

Comment: please post your code directly and not as a screenshot. Use the [edit] link below the question toedit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reuse cipher instances and make sure the IV is correct every time you use one for decryption.